# Qt invisible button not working on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, button, invisible

I am trying to create a sheet music viewer in Qt c++ on Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi. Im using Qt Creator 4.8.1, based on Qt 5.12.0. As part of it, I want large invisible buttons on the lower corners of the screen, which when clicked (or tapped on a touchscreen) would take me to the previous or next page. I built a small proof of concept app that works great in Windows, but in Ubuntu Studio 18.04, displays large white squares instead of invisible ones. Here are some of the things I have tried (based on QPushbutton):

```
xButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");   
xButton->setWindowOpacity(0.0);
xButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;");
```

I'm not sure if this is some kind of Windows vs X quirk, or if I'm just missing something else.

Comment: Transparency in Qt widgets seems to be a thing which doesn't work on every system reliably. (It might depend on the resp. rendering engine "under the hood".) Alternatively, you could consider to derive a custom button class where you tweak the `paintEvent()` to just draw nothing. Additionally, you may have to grant that the button doesn't clear it's background but I'm currently not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: An alternative could be to drop the buttons concept and overriding the mouse events in the widget you use for drawing of the contents. That's probably the simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the override paintEvent() solution, which turned out to be pretty simple: 

class InvisButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InvisButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {}  // uncomment this line for invisible button

    QSize sizeHint() const override;
};